# C++ count digits and characters

Tags: c++, arrays, function, file-io, fstream

I'm pretty new to C++ and I need to write a program that can count number of digits, characters, space symbols and other symbols. I decided to start with counting the number of digits. This is my code so far:

```
 int main() {
     int n = 0;
     int numb = 0;

     ifstream read("Data.txt");

     n = symbCounter(n, read);
     numb = numbCounter(n, read, numb);
     cout << numb; // this is for quick testing

     return 0;
 }

 int symbCounter(int &n, ifstream &read) {

     char ch;
     while (!read.eof()) {
         read.get(ch);
         n++;

     }
     return n;

 }

 int numbCounter(int &n, ifstream &read, int counter) {

     char sk[n];

     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         read.get(sk[i]);
         if (sk[i] == '1' || sk[i] == '2' || sk[i] == '3' || sk[i] == '4' || sk[i] == '5' || sk[i] == '6' || sk[i] == '7' || sk[i] == '8' || sk[i] == '9' || sk[i] == '0')
             counter++;
     };

     return counter;
 }
```

But the console gives me the value 0. What am I doing wrong? And how do I count just characters, excluding digits or spaces? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For starters you might be interested in the [`cctype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cctype) header

Comment: Does this even compile? It shouldn't! `char sk[n];` is not allowed. The size of an array must be known at compile time. This `n` is only known to the function at run time. (At least some compilers do offer this as an extension you have to enable though).

Comment: Hmm it did compile. I use CodeBlocks. And this header will be very helphul. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the functions defined in the `<cctype>` header like

```
isalpha()
isblank()
iscntrl()
isdigit()
isspace()
```

and others to check for specific types of characters.
See [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/) for example.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out! Will try this tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

In your `symbCounter` method, you read through the file to the end.  When you try to read from the file in your `numbCounter` method, the calls to `read` will return `EOF` since you are at the end of the file.  You can return to the beginning by calling

```
read.seekg(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the the beginning of the file for numCounter;
right after

```
int numbCounter(int &n, ifstream &read, int counter) {
```

add

```
read.clear();
read.seekg(0, ios::beg);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was helphul.